# Kth number in lexicographically sorted numbers from 1 to N

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Given an integer N, find the kth ranked no in a lexicographically sorted numbers array from 1 to N.

Ex: N = 12

Lexicographically sorted numbers are: [1, 10, 11, 12, 2 , 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

If K=4, the program should return: 12.

The complexity of the program should be O(logN).

The array is generated for the purpose of explaining and not provided as an input. Generation of the array and sorting will take Nlog(N) time, thus defeating the purpose.

I recently faced this question in an interview process. Could not figure out the solution in given time complexity, hence asking for help

Thanks!!

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you should return and what are you given? The way you phrased the question seems to be the question to find the kth biggest number in the lexicographically sorted array, but you say that the program should return 12 which is simply the kth lexicographical number in the set. Also can there be duplicates in the array?

Comment: It is the kth lexicographical number in the set . The program can only take the number N and K as input and return the kth lexicographical number. The numbers in the set are unique from 1 to N.

Comment: I have only generated the array to explain the question, no array of numbers is provided as input

Comment: It is a bisection search using lexicographic order as total ordering.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I don't follow - how would you formulate this bisection? (Remember that we don't have the actual list, just N and K)

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread the question. You could possibly use a min heap to retrieve the kth value.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque I still can't follow :) how would you use a heap when all you're given two integers, N and K, and are asked to provide the Kth number in all lexicographically sorted numbers from 1 to N in O(log N) time?

Comment: Oh, I see... I really did misunderstand the question...

Comment: check [`from lexicographic import Lexicographic`](https://github.com/Grijesh-Chauhan/Interviews/tree/master/GoMechanic) and run `Lexicographic(12)[4] == 12` or iterate over `[n for n in Lexicographic(115)]` ... Let me know if someone need explanation, I will add an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take N = 13000, K = 12031. Each digit from 1 to 9 when assigned as left-most gets:

```
                                      total
1 single digit number 9 * 1              9
10 two-digit numbers  9 * 10            99
100 three-digit numbers 9 * 100        999
1000 four-digit numbers 9 * 1000      9999
10000 five-digit numbers      --->  here we have to start examining

                                             Total
                                             ----
1 gets 13000 - 8 * (1 + 10 + 100 + 1000)  =  4112 of them
2 gets 1111                                  5223
3 gets 1111                                  6334
4 gets 1111                                  7445
5 gets 1111                                  8556
6 gets 1111                                  9667
7 gets 1111                                  10778
8 gets 1111                                  11889
9 gets 1111 ----> answer is somewhere here
```

Answer: `9xxx`. Now the second digit. For each number that ends in one or more zeros, we have to count all lower numbers with an equivalent prefix.

```
3 numbers with zero or nothing before 9000   11892
9 90 900

100 + 9 numbers with 90xx
9000 9001 9002.., but also 901 902..         12001
```

Answer: `91xx`. Third digit.

```
2 numbers with zero or nothing before 9100
91 910                                       12003

10 four-digit numbers with 0 as third digit
9100 9101 9102..                             12013

1 number with zero or nothing before 9110
911                                          12014

10 numbers with 1 as third digit
9110 9111 9112..                             12024

1 number with zero or nothing before 9120
912                                          12025

+ 6
```

Answer: `9126`